# The background color of dark style keyboard become lighter

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'am try to display system dark keyboard, and The code is:

```
self.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
```

The self is a subclass of UITextField. And the result became[image]

At the first time, the color was as dark as another normal system dark keyboard when the key appeared, and then the color of this keyboard changed and became lighter than normal dark keyboard.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please check your background behind keyboard.(When keyboard opens)
If any UIView or UIViewController or other control background have a light color then it will be possible to display light color.

Comment: System pop up a new window for displaying the keyboard and I didn't change any color of any subviews of the window. I even didn't touch those views

Comment: If system pop up a new window then please check background of its previous UIViewController.
Exa:- pop up a new window its name is "B". and previous UIViewController then its name is "A.".
In above case check all controls of "A" UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set this throughout your app use below code in your **AppDelegate** `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

**For TextFields:**

```
[[UITextField appearance] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];
```

**For TextViews:**

```
[[UITextView appearance] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];
```